# Prove time of $k^{th}$ success is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am stuck on Erhan Cinlar's "Probability and Stochastic" Chapter 2 Section 5 Problem 26:

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$, ... be independent Bernoulli variables with the same success probability $p$. Define, for each $k$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$, the time of $k^{th}$ success by $T_k=\inf\{n\geq 1: S_n(\omega)\geq k\}$, $\omega\in\Omega$. Note that this yields $T_k(\omega)=+\infty$ if $S_n(\omega)<k$ for all $n$. Show that $T_k$ is a random variable for each $k$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$

$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i$. $\mathscr{H}$ is the set of all events.

I know that $\{S_n\geq k\}$ is $\mathscr{H}$-measurable. But I am not sure how to continue.

Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you define all the terms like $S_n$ and $\mathcal{H}$ for those who do not possess the book.

Comment: $T_k=n$ if and only if $S_1< k, S_2 < k,...,S_{n-1} < k$ and $S_n \geq k$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $T_k^{-1}(A)=\bigcup\limits_{m\in A}((\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}\{S_i <k\})\cap\{S_m\geq k\})$